# Resource entry com.crashlytics.android.build_id is already defined

Tags: java, android, build, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

My project was working and everything was fine but have no idea what happened suddenly that I'm getting error when I want to build my project. This is Gradle output:

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/android/MY-Project/build/intermediates/res/project/debug/values/values.xml:265: error: Resource entry com.crashlytics.android.build_id is already defined.
/Users/admin/Desktop/android/MY-Project/build/intermediates/res/project/debug/values/com_crashlytics_build_id.xml:9: Originally defined here.
```

Since both of these files are auto generated I cannot do anything :(

1. I tried to clean project by Build>"Clean project" but nothing happened.
2. I tried to clean project by `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` but nothing happened.
3. I tried to invalidate cache of Android Studio by File>"Invalidate caches / Restart" but nothing happened.
4. I even restarted my f.laptop but still same problem displays when I build the project.

I have this classpath in my build script but as mentioned it was working...

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I encountered the same problem.  I think it might have something to do with having different manifest files with different package names.  (e.g. com.something.free and com.something.paid).

Comment: @metaphyze thanks man. Funny thing is I checked out to its parent branch and tried to build it to see what happens. Same thing happened :( so confused... So should be more serious...

Comment: I think I see the problem.  Do you have your crashlytics files committed to source control?  Assuming you're using git, you need to untrack them (not delete them from the file system).  I had mine committed.  Here's what I did.  1)  add com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics-build.properties to the .gitignore file  2) git rm --cached all those files.  This will remove them source control tracking but leave them on the file system.   3) Clean the build.   There's a comment in those files that says "#Do NOT modify, delete, or commit to source control!"

Comment: Couldn't figure out what was the problem but pulled project again into new directory and in this directory was working fine. I will write the answer if I could figure out what was that problem. btw, new pull of repo fixed this mysterious problem!

Comment: @metaphyze, Thanks man for your time, I checked repo and those files are not under version control.

Comment: I had the same problem, one of my dependencies had mistakenly added the com.crashlytics.android.build_id via craslytics's auto genereted xml file. Deleting it fixed it for me

Comment: This problem just came out of nowhere for me. As we are all suddenly seeing this, perhaps we've all updated Android Studio, or Android Tools, recently?

Comment: @Justin yes I have recently updated my gradle stuff, that might be the trigger but for my case I had always had that problem but did not recognised it since.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem, one of my dependencies had mistakenly added the com.crashlytics.android.build_id via craslytics's auto genereted xml file.

It was a library project and deleting :

```
library/src/main/assets/crashlytics-build.properties
library/src/main/res/values/com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: It happened to me again after I installed Fabric plugin. I uninstalled the plugin but problem was there. Then deleted mentioned files from my dependencies and problem fixed. Thanks @wrecker

Comment: I got this issue after updating an old code base from Crashlytics to Fabric and tried this suggestion (at least just deleting the .xml file in my case), which worked. I also confirmed it was the correct solution with the Fabric support team.

Answer (score 38):

I have an app of two flavors: Debug and Release, with two manifests and two distinct packages com.myapp.release and com.myapp.debug for each flavor, respectively.

After migration from Fabric.io to Firebase Crashalytics, a Gradle warning 
appeared about duplicate `com_crashlytics_build_id.xml`:

```
/home/.../app/build/generated/fabric/res/flavor1/debug/values/com_crashlytics_build_id.xml  [string/com.crashlytics.android.build_id] /home/.../app/build/generated/crashlytics/res/flavor2/debug/values/com_crashlytics_build_id.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

**Fix:**
 in `build.gradle`

**remove**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
```

**remove**

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.

My mistake is I add fabric plugin and firebaseCrashlytics plugin on my gradle.
(reason : plugin build id duplicate crash)

You must fix select A and B plugin.

A : `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics`

B : `apply plugin: 'io.fabric`

Comment: should we add both or old fabric needs to be removed?

Comment: @GiteekaSawlani You should remove either.
But i recommend removing the fabric. Because firebase's crashlytics was officially released [ https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android ]

Answer (score 8):

## Fix different `io.fabric.tools:gradle` versions

Different `io.fabric.tools:gradle` versions in the app and library caused this for me.

I'd the following in the app's `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
```

And the following in the library's `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
```

I changed both to following to fix it:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
```

PS: We need better error messages. As programmers we waste of lot of time when the error messages are not only bad, but as in this case, downright misleading.

Answer (score 0):

remove this also besides fabric

```
crashlytics {
   enableNdk true
 }
```